# Get view to rotate with gyro

Tags: android, view, gyroscope

I want to rotate my device and have the main view rotate with it, sort of like a compass. I have literally no idea how to do this, I've looked at the developer API intro guide and it doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

This blog post has exactly what you  need to start developing your app (**which uses the magnetometer and accelerometer to create a compass effect**): http://www.codingforandroid.com/2011/01/using-orientation-sensors-simple.html

Don't forget to set your `AndroidManifest.xml` Activity to point to `CompassActivity`, and add the permissions for COURSE and FINE locations.